# Read a csv file in c# Web Application (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I am new to C# and Visual Studio. I am trying to read a `.csv` file into my ASP.NET MVC project and can not find the correct tutorials. I have tried multiple different ways and keep getting the same errors on the same pieces of code listed below is the code I have.

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Fifa19TeamBuilder.Models;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Controller = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller;
using ActionResult = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server;

namespace Fifa19TeamBuilder.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult About()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Team(*HttpPostedFileBase* postedFile)
        {
            List<TeamModel> team = new List<TeamModel>();
            string filePath = string.Empty;

            if (postedFile != null)
            {
                string path = *Server*.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.*FileName*);
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.*FileName*);
                postedFile.*SaveAs*(filePath);

                //Read the contents of CSV file.
                string csvData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);

                //Execute a loop over the rows.
                foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                    {
                        team.Add(new TeamModel
                        {
                            ID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Split(',')[0]),
                            player_name = row.Split(',')[1],
                            quality = row.Split(',')[2],
                            overall = row.Split(',')[2],
                            club = row.Split(',')[2],
                            league = row.Split(',')[2],
                            nationality = row.Split(',')[2],
                            position = row.Split(',')[2],
                            age = row.Split(',')[2],
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            return View(team);
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Fifa19TeamBuilder.Models
{
    public class TeamModel
    {
        public int ID { set; get; }
        public string player_name { set; get; }
        public string quality { set; get; }
        public string overall { set; get; }
        public string club { set; get; }
        public string league { set; get; }
        public string nationality { set; get; }
        public string position { set; get; }
        public string age { set; get; }
    }
}
```

Error

> CS0246 The type or namespace name 'HttpPostedFileBase' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error #2:

> CS0103 The name 'Server' does not exist in current context

Error #3:

> CS1061 'HttpPostedFileBaseModelBinder' does not contain a definition for 'SaveAs' and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type 'HttpPostedFileBaseModelBinder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an reference)

Can someone please help me all the tutorials I found was for VS 2010, 2015 none for 2017 not sure if that makes a difference. I am just trying to read a csv file from inside the project folder and put it in a `List<>`. I do not need to upload the file. I have * where it shows the errors.

This is where I got the code:

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-Read-and-Display-CSV-file-Text-File-data-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

Comment: if you don't need to upload the file you don't need to use `HttpPostedFile` This class is used when the files are uploaded from a client. You can use a simple string if you need to send the name of the file inside your project folder : `public ActionResult Team(string fileName)`

Comment: Thanks @marc_s I have removed HttpPostedFile and I am using csvHelper reader and writer